# How can I center without <center></center>?

Tags: html

I've got this code at the moment:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><center> enE jk <br> 5.6 </center></td>
    <td><center> mtE hp <br>  6.4 </center></td>
    <td><center> hpE eb <br> HML </center></td>
    <td><center> reE pm <br> 514 </center></td>
    <td><center> hpE eb <br> HP2</center></td>
```

However, I don't want to have to keep using `<center></center>`...

Any help?

Comment: `<td style="text-align: center;"></td>` also.. "The <center> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead." - w3schools

Comment: Also, here's some information to get you started on [using CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the CSS property [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>enE jk<br>5.6</td>
    <td>mtE hp<br>6.4</td>
    <td>hpE eb<br>HML</td>
    <td>reE pm<br>514</td>
    <td>hpE eb<br>HP2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `<center></center>` it is depreciated.  Instead use the `text-align` property which is made for positioning text.

You just need to add a style to your `td` elements and use the `center` property.  You can do it like this:

```
<style>
td {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Or you could add `text-align: center;` directly into each `td` like this:

```
<td style="text-align:center"> enE jk <br> 5.6 </td>
```

Or using and external style script (recommended).

Here is a working snippet:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>
     enE jk <br> 5.6
  </td>
  <td>
    mtE hp <br> 6.4
  </td>
  <td>
    hpE eb <br> HML
  </td>
  <td>
    reE pm <br> 514
  </td>
  <td>
     hpE eb <br> HP2
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

---

`text-align` has three properties:

`center` which centers the text

`left` which aligns the text to the left

`right` which aligns the text to the right.

Reference for the [`text-align` property can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp)